# I am working on SUMO and I generated a trip file from an OD-matrice using od2trips tool but I couldn't define the vehicle type

Tags: sumo

SUMO, defining vehicle types in generated trips from od2trips.

In the documentation, it suggests to load external additional file (`--additional-file`) but how could I load that file please? What to write on the cmdline?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write
`sumo -n net.net.xml -a additional.xml -r routes.xml`.